# How to record a video with C#

Tags: c#, image-processing, video-capture, emgucv, video-encoding

I have a C# WPF MVVM application that needs to record and take pictures. The camera is an industrial camera [STC-MCA5MUSB3](http://www.sentechamerica.com/En/Cameras/USB/STC-MCA5MUSB3).

The only experience I have with image manipulation is with OpenCV in C++, so I am thinking about using [Emgu](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/Main_Page), which is just OpenCV for C#, but I feel like this might be too much.

My program has to show a preview of the image in a 400x300 pixels and be able to take 5MP pictures and record Full HD 1920x1080 movies.

The algorithm I have in my mind is:

1. Receive a 5MP frame from the camera.
2. If the user pressed the "Take Picture" button, save this frame on the pictures folder.
3. Scale down the frame to Full HD and pass it to a library that will add this frame to a movie, like a pipeline, and recorded it in real time in the computer's HDD.
4. Scale down the frame to 400x300px and show it in the preview area in the screen.

I am afraid this might be too much for the computer to process, specially in C#, so I am open to suggestion on the algorithm and on libraries.

Comment: have you tried [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3566/DirectX-Capture-Class-Library) link?

Comment: Looks interesting, but it's from 2008...

Comment: ...And the example files from 2003

Comment: ...And it crasher with my camera...the "refresh" version from 2008 doesn't even runs